# After remesh my 3D logo is not smooth on the oval walls

Tags: mesh, smooth, remesh

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZmdbRRFTDc&ab_channel=toericht

I'm a new user of Blender and I'm really struggling with getting a nice shape for the logo.

After extruding, remeshing and sculpting some of the oval walls of my logo don't look very smooth - some of the walls are jagged (screens attached).

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with my settings, as the logo looks so much better in the video.

Comment: Have you shade smoothed and enabled the Auto Smooth option? If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/